# Why is analog stick drift so associated with the Nintendo Switch's Joycons?

Tags: controllers, nintendo-switch

AFAIK, analog stick drift has been reported in every analog stick controller I'm familiar with, apparently fixable by painstakingly scraping out dust and gunk. However, the issue seems to be most widely reported in the Switch's Joycons by far, and for some yet-to-be-confirmed reason (dust, wear), it seems much harder to fix. Anecdotally, I haven't heard anybody I knew complain about analog stick drift until a friend's Switch started drifting; I have never owned a Switch and have never ran into the issue on any controller.

Is this just media hyperfocus on an extremely popular console, or is analog stick drift actually a much more frequent and harder to fix issue in Switches? If it is, then can someone offer a hardware comparison against more robust controllers, with more detail beyond "dust and wear" and perhaps also explaining why they don't just copy better analog sticks?

Comment: I fear that if anyone knew what the exact issue is, Nintendo would have fixed it long ago since by now the thing is costing them quite a bit of money thanks to extended free repair policy, multiple class actions and so on... Some claim that the issue is due to poor quality contacts that get easily damaged, some other attribute the problem to dust getting inside the controller since the stick housing is actually open and it is possible for external dust to reach the potentiometer sensor...

Comment: I challenge the claim _"the issue seems to be most widely reported in the Switch's Joycons by far"_. Were you around for N64?

Comment: It is a large issue on all Nintendo consoles and the Switch is just the newest Nintendo console which is why everything's going after the switch now. My Wii Nunchucks had drifting and so does one of my Switch Joycons